# Black screen after instalation of KDE Desktop

Tags: 12.04, kde

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I have installed `KDE-plasma-netbook` for testing, but when i have selected that session from login screen, i hear the login sound but i got nothing on the desktop (screen). It's completely empty blank screen. Help me to solve this.

EDIT: Here we go! i can get <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> launcher and i can launch dolphin or any application but my desktop is look like the image i am attaching now .[image]

Any Help appreciated ,:)

Comment: Could you post a screenshot? What do you mean by blank screen? Don't see anything but mouse and system responds? Like if you press ALT+F2 does it work?

Comment: i can see mouse but there is no desktop , no system menu .its just a empty desktop and screen shot means i got nothing there . how could i ?

Comment: You didn't answer his last question.

Comment: @LnxSlck Hi i have tried and i got it .ok i will add the remaining thing in the main post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok i got solved my issue . the mistake i did is `sudo apt-get install kde-plasma-netbook`. so its gave me back a blank desktop . but i am using a PC so i have tried with `sudo apt-get install kde-plasma-desktop` and its worked like charm . i have logout and login and now i have my desktop back .

Comment: This solved my problem.  I'm using 3.8.0-26-generic #38-Ubuntu.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem, but didn't want plasma-desktop as I'm installing on a cutdown netbook. Eventually found

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> then type `plasma-netbook`

to get the interface. Looked in System Settings > Startup and Shutdown and noticed that the "plasma-netbook" entry had a "--desktop" option. I disabled it and created an entry with just the "plasma-netbook" command. The system now works without having to have installed the "kde-plasma-desktop" package.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 4):

I have found that this is caused by the `KDE menu | system settings | Workspace behavior | Workspace | Workspace Type` being set to "netbook".

If you change that setting to Desktop things should work fine.

Of course, this presumes you **have** a working desktop available to do this- I got a temporary one through using <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and typing plasma-desktop in.

If you are stuck on the commandline then go to `~/.kde/share/autostart` and remove `--desktop` from the first line (starting with Exec) of the plasma-netbook.desktop file (or just delete the whole file). Sync, reboot and you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should've installed `kubuntu-destkop` instead of the netbook.... Try to install `kubuntu-desktop`with `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`

Comment: Thank you for the answer but i don't want Kubuntu desktop , because i just want to try the KDE but kubuntu desktop will gives its pkg's also .

Comment: Er, try "sudo apt-get install kde" then. If not I can't help.

Comment: actually "raja@badfox:~/Documents$ apt-cache search  kde-plasma-netbook
kde-plasma-netbook - KDE Plasma Netbook and minimal set of applications" i need to try it .

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem,
try this

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

if it it says KDE already installed, then type the below command

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: PPAs are not community-supported software. Is there a way to accomplish the same goal with supported software from the Ubuntu repositories?